# Replace every second blank line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way in Notepad++ to replace every other blank line? The number of filled lines is random and so is the occurrence of empty lines.

Is this differentiation possible with a non-uniform spacing or is it outwith the scope of expressions in Notepad?

EDIT: I'm looking to replace every second occurrence of a blank line.

For example:-

```
    Bed
    Bee

    [BLANK A]

    Bible
    Bible
    Bird
    Bomb

    [BLANK B]

    Book
    Boss
    Bottle
    Bowl
    Box

    [BLANK A]

    Boy
    Brain
    Bridge
    Butterfly
    Button
    Cappuccino
    Car

    [BLANK B]

    Car-race
    Carpet
    Carrot
    Cave
    Chair

    [BLANK A]

    Chess Board
    Chief
    Child
    Chisel
    Chocolates
```

Where A and B should be replaced separately.

Comment: Please, give an example text with expected result.

Comment: To be clear, there is **1** blank line between `Bee`  and `Bible` that you want to replace with `Something A` and **1** blank line between `Bomb` and  `Book ` that you want to replace with `Something B`. Am I right? Please again, give your input file **and** expected result, do not mix before and after in a same example. Between `Bee` and `Bible` is there a single blank line, more than one, something  else?

Comment: Is there somewhere in the file 2 or more consecutive blank lines?

Comment: Have a try with: Find: `((?:.+\R)+)(\R)(?:((?:.+\R)+)(\R))?` and Replace: `$1[BLANK A]$2(?3$3[BLANK B]$4)`. Tell me if it works for you and I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Toto that works perfectly. Thank you and apologies for the lack of clarity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `((?:.+\R)+)(\R)(?:((?:.+\R)+)(\R))?`
- Replace with: `$1[BLANK A]$2(?3$3[BLANK B]$4)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(               # group 1 (will contain consecutive non blank lines)
  (?:           # non capture group
    .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
    \R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
  )+            # end group, may appear 1 or more times
)               # end group 1
(\R)            # group 2, any kind of linebreak (i.e. first blank line)
(?:             # non capture group
  (             # group 3, same pattern as in group 1
    (?:
      .+
      \R
    )+
  )
  (\R)          # group 4, any kind of linebreak (i.e. second blank line)
)?              # end group, optional
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1              # content of group 1 (non blank lines)
[BLANK A]       # replacement for first blank line
$2              # content of group 2, (a linebreak)
(?3             # if group 3 exists:
    $3              # content of group 3 (non blank lines)
    [BLANK B]       # replacement for second blank line
    $4              # content of group 4, (a linebreak)
)               # end condition
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you. Is there a way to select the alternate blank lines?

Comment: @AlfieLC: What do means by “alternate blank lines”? Please, edit your question and add sample text  and expected result.

Comment: The lines that your solution misses. The expected result should be to be able to work "both ways". Basically, how do I invert your solution to select the other blank lines.

Comment: I added an example to the question.

Comment: @AlfieLC: I've updated my answer to resolve your real case.

Answer (score 0):

Menu `Search > Replace...`

Find what: `^(\s+)*\n`

Replace: `(leave empty)`

Set Radio button to `regular expression`.

This should replace all blank lines independently of how many spaces there are.

Comment: Thanks but the question was is it possible to distinguish between every second blank line.

For example:-
LINE 1: Apple
LINE 2: Blank A
LINE 3: Pear
LINE 4: Blank B
LINE 5: Banana
LINE 6: Blank A,

where blanks A and B can be replaced discriminantly.